# Source Radak psalm 110

Tags: sources-mekorot, commentaries

In the Koren Tehillim on Psalm 110 there is a footnote stating that: Radak goes as far as to present a 'Christian' interpretation of our psalm, which he persuasively refutes on both linguistic and theological grounds. This refutation was censored in most editions for centuries, and was inaccessible to the avarage student until recently.

I would really love to know the source for this interpretation and the refitation of RaDak and am hoping someone could provide a English translation.

Comment: FTR: About two centuries after Radak, [Lipman Muhlhausen](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yom-Tov_Lipmann-Muhlhausen) collected a number of censored passages from Radak’s com. on Tehilim which he appended to the end of his own ‘Sefer Nizzahon’. This particular passage you ask about is quoted [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=45562&st=&pgnum=209&hilite=). (The earliest copy of the SN that exists is only 1644.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can read his commentary on the psalm in Hebrew [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=21413&st=&pgnum=246), from which I took the paragraph divisions. The text (copied from [here](https://www.mgketer.org/study)) is:

> והנוצרים מפרשים זה המזמור על ישו. ואמרו , כי בפסוק הראשון יתבאר בו האב והבן; שהם קוראים "נאם יי' לאדוני" (לעיל , א) בקמץ הנו"ן , ואמרו: היאך יֹאמר יי' "לאדנָי"? אלא שהם שנים , והרוח - השלישי. ועוד טעות אחר קוראים בזה המזמור: "עמך נדבות" (לעיל , ג) - קוראים אותו 'עִמך' , בחיריק העי"ן. ואומרים "בהדרי קדש" (שם) - הוא ה"קדש" שנולד "מרחם" (שם).
>
> ואתה תאמר להם על טעות קריאתם , כי גירולמש המעתיק שלהם טעה; כי "לאדני" (לעיל , א) - בחירק הנו"ן , והוא אומר על דוד , כמו שפירשנו; ואיך יוכלו להחזיק טעות איש אחד כנגד אנשים רבים? כי ממזרח שמש ועד מבואו ימצא בכל הספרים בחרק הנו"ן , וכן "עמך נדבות" (לעיל , ג) - בפתח העי"ן; והלא הם אומרים כי התורה שלנו עדות להם , אם כן יאמינו בעֵד!
>
> ועל טעות אמונתם תאמר להם: אם האב והבן הם אלהות , אין צריך האחד לחבירו , כי לא יקרא 'אלוה' אם יצטרך לזולתו; ואיך יאמר האב לבן "שב לימיני עד אשית אויביך" (לעיל , א)? אם כן צריך הוא לימינו ולעזרתו , אם כן חולשה אתו , והאלוה אינו חלש וחסר היכולת!
>
> והיאך אמר לו "אתה כהן לעולם" (לעיל , ד) , ומקודם לא היה כהן ונגיד? ואם יאמרו: 'כהן' כמשמעו , ויאמרו: מהיום ואילך תהיה הכהונה בענין אחר , לא שיהיו מקריבים בשר ודם כמו שהיו מקריבים עד היום , אלא לחם ויין , כמו שעשה מלכי צדק , שנאמר "ומלכי צדק מלך שלם הוציא לחם ויין והוא כהן לאל עליון" (בר' יד , יח) - אמור להם: למי אומר "אתה כהן" (לעיל , ד)? לבן הוא אומר , כמו שאמר מתחלת המזמור עד זה הפסוק , וכן מזה הפסוק עד סוף המזמור! והכהן הוא העובד המקריב , והאלוה לא יקריב , אבל יקריבו לפניו! ואם יאמר לאדם בעולם - ואינו מדרך המזמור - למי יאמר? כי הם אין להם לכהן משפחה , אלא כל הבא ימלא את ידו (ע"פ מ"א יג , לג) , ואם כן , למי יאמר "נשבע יי' ולא ינחם אתה כהן לעולם"? ועוד , למה שִנה רצונו , כי מתחלה צוה להקריב בשר ואחר כך לחם ויין? ואיך אמר "ולא ינחם" , והרי נחם? והלא לא נתנה התורה לזמן! והנה מלאכי , חותם הנביאים , אמר: "זכרו תורת משה עבדי אשר צויתי אותו בחורב... חוקים ומשפטים" (מל' ג , כב); ואמר: "הנה אנכי שולח לכם את אליה הנביא" (שם , כג) , והנה אליהו לא בא עדיין , ולא יבא עד זמן ימות המשיח;
>
> והנה אמר , שיזכרו תורת משה לעשותה , כמו שצוה אותו בסיני , לא כמו שצוה ישו; מזה תראה , כי לא תשתנה התורה לעולם , אלא כמו שנתנה למשה כן תהיה לעולם. ועוד: אמר "מחץ ביום אפו מלכים" (לעיל , ה) , ואיה המלחמות שנלחם ישו והמלכים אשר נצח? ואיך אמר "ידין בגוים מלא גויות" (לעיל , ו) , והוא לא בא לדון אלא הנשמות ולהושיען? ואמר: על כן ירים ראש - ועד היום ההוא לא הרים ראשו? יפקחו העורים את עיניהם , ויאמרו: "אך שקר נחלו אבותינו" (יר' טז , יט).

He quotes the Christian interpretation as follows:

> The Christians interpret this psalm about Jesus. They say that the first verse refers to the father and the son, since they read "the word of YHVH to the Lord" with a *kamats* in the *nun* [i.e. אֲדֹנָי rather than אֲדֹנִי], and they say: How can YHVH speak to "the Lord"? It must be that they are two, and the spirit is third. And another mistake they make in reading this psalm: They read "with you (עִמְּךָ) is generosity" with a *chirik* [rather than "your nation (עַמְּךָ) is generosity"]. And they say the "beauty of holiness" is the holy one who was born from the womb.

His objections against this interpretation are basically these:

- Verse 1: The correct reading is לַאדֹנִי, a reference to David, and גירולמש [maybe a mistake for גירונמש, i.e. [Hieronymus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerome)] their translator erred in reading לַאדֹנָי, while all the manuscripts read לַאדֹנִי. Since they claim the Jewish Torah is their "witness," they should at least believe in the witness
- Theologically, if either the father or the son is "in need" of the other, neither can be a deity. From the fact that one says to the other "sit at my right side," it seems he is in need of the other
- V. 4: If the father is telling the son to be a "priest," but he shouldn't be the one serving; others should be serving him
- The Christians interpret Malchizedek's offering of bread and wine (the name mentioned in this psalm as well) to mean that God decided to replace the sacrifices with [bread and wine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eucharist). If there was a replacement, it's inappropriate to say "he will not change his mind." (He also brings reasons based on Malachi 3:22 in support of the Torah not changing, but this is only a side point to this psalm.)
- V. 5: The implication is that Jesus would fight wars, but Jesus didn't fight any wars
- V. 6: If Jesus only came to save souls, he shouldn't be killing people
- V. 7: This verse says "he will raise his head," but to this day Jesus hasn't "raised his head" (returned)

Comment: Thank you so much! Spot on, just what I was searching for.